# Create new folder in Angular

Tags: angular-cli

I want to create new folder with code `ng g c recipes --spec false` but in the terminal the results is Unknown option: '--spec'
Unknown option: 'false' .

Comment: Read the docs: https://angular.io/cli/generate#component-command

Answer (score 2):

The correct option for not generating `.spec.ts`-files is `--skipTests true`.

(This will generate a component btw, but since you tried this direction of option I assume you meant that.)

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `--spec false` with `--skipTests=true`.

You can find the full option list in here: https://angular.io/cli/generate#component